# universalimageloader loading half url

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image loader for loading image from server but i am getting one issue while loading an image URL which contains ampersand (&). Its loading only before part of ampersand.

This universalimageloader version i am using

```
'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
```

this is my code

```
mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.img_no_image_screen3)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.img_no_image_screen3)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.img_no_image_screen3)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .build();
 mImageLoader.displayImage(productInfo.getProductImage(), 
 productImage, imageOptions, this )
```

[this](https://partycity3.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_sq_?$_500x500_$&$product=PartyCity/816681_full) is my url which i want to load , but loading [this](https://partycity3.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_sq_?$_500x500_$) url

this is perfectly loading other image URL only getting issue with above attacked URL.
Can any tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are providing this URL to this library.

Comment: try `piccasso or glide` orpost your code here

Comment: @VishalYadav is there any to resolve this issue without change loader , i have added code in my question

Comment: `imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);` try this one may be it woks for you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Picasso`](https://github.com/square/picasso):

```
Picasso.get().load("https://partycity3.scene7.com/is/image/PartyCity/_sq_?$_500x500_$&$product=PartyCity/816681_full").into(yourImageView);
```

Don't forget to add this

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

to your Gradle.